# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.lang.reflect.Constructor org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.accessibleConstructor after Spring Upgrade

Tags: java, spring

I am deploying two apps on Wildfly 23.0.2 that we both are currently in the process of upgrading. We ramped up Java from 7 to 17, Springframework from 4.3.24  to 5.3.22 and Hibernate from 3.6 to 5.6. After starting the app, I immediately get the following error... but just for one app, the other is running fine with almost the same dependencies in pom.xml:

```
14:20:38,360 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 182) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."myapp.war".undertow-deployment: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."myapp.war".undertow-deployment: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.servlet.ServletException: Failed to instantiate WebApplicationInitializer class
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@23.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:81)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:513)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.servlet.ServletException: Failed to instantiate WebApplicationInitializer class
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:257)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@23.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:96)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@23.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:78)
        ... 8 more
Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: Failed to instantiate WebApplicationInitializer class
        at deployment.myapp.war//org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:160)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:204)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:187)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@23.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@23.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@23.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@23.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@23.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:255)
        ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.lang.reflect.Constructor org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.accessibleConstructor(java.lang.Class, java.lang.Class[])'
        at deployment.myapp.war//org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:157)
        ... 20 more
```

I debug into `org/springframework/web/SpringServletContainerInitializer#onStartup()` where the call causing the error happens and I can see that it happens when a class that extends `AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer` is processed. When I remove the extension, this class is not processed and the error does not occur, despite 5 other files are waiting to be called the exact same way.

The `SpringServletContainerInitializer#onStartup()` where the error occurs:

[image]

The error occurs when processing a file that we use with Spring Security for Keycloak auth. Through extending the `AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer`, this file gets regarded in the `SpringServletContainerInitializer#onStartup()`:

```
package com.myapp.security.web.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;
import org.springframework.security.web.context.AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer;

@Profile("keycloak-auth")
public class SecurityWebInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

    
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] {SecurityConfig.class};
    }   
}
```

I have:

- made sure that the `spring-core-5.3.22.jar` is in the `WEB-INF/lib` directory and
- that there are no concurrent versions of any Spring package in the directory.
- that no old Spring.Core versions are in `wildfly/modules` directory.
- Wiped the Maven Repository that contains all Springframework jars.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Can you post the code of the class where the error is occurring as well

Comment: Have added the info.

Answer (score 0):

I got the problem fixed in the meantime. I installed a new wildfly, wiped the maven repo and tested serveral things but nothing helped. This morning I entered the OLD Spring version in my POM.xml that we upgraded from and I compiled. The system went over this error. Then I put back the Spring version that we upgraded to in the POM, compiled again and the error was gone. Must have been some sort of weird caching issue at the end of Maven.